# How to incorporate SOAP webservices within a vertx server

Tags: java, vert.x, vertx3

Is it possible to integrate SOAP web services within vertx server?

Comment: You mean to consume an existing webservices or write one of your own?

Comment: Actually, to write my own inside a vertx application

Comment: Haven't worked,  but, should work mostly like any other java code

Comment: Actually, because of the asynchronous nature of vertx i don't know if it will work

Comment: Your question is async and not exactly vert.x-related, as prasun suggested as well.  

You should use some kind of cuncurrency/promises to handle the request in an async way, see here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16539245/java-equivalent-of-c-sharp-async-await
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142915/how-do-you-create-an-asynchronous-http-request-in-java
http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2013/05/java-8-definitive-guide-to.html

Comment: I was thinking about using the https://github.com/reficio/soap-ws - only for SOAP parsing for now (soap-builder module only - not server as it starts it's own http server - I don't know how is it implemented...).