# Angular App integrate with QuickBooks Web connector

Tags: angularjs, quickbooks

I have an angular application need to integrate with Quickbooks Desktop application through web connector. I did a search around and only find node.js package for integrating with QBs web connector. Are there people there who tried to integrate using angular? thanks.

Comment: Hoping to walk you thru the solution to get things in place for you,
I will need some more info below to provide you a working solution. What other tech stack are you using along with Angular ? The reason I'm asking this is because Angular is purely a client side framework and you will need a server side technology to interface with QuickBooks Webconnector.

Comment: No it's just angular application with no real backend. I think i will have to end up having to set up a vert.x backend to handle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A viable working solution would be something as described below.

QBWC works not as the server but as a client to a SOAP web service in pull mechanism at regular intervals from a SOAP web service.

So a viable solution is if using angularjs for client side, use a backend interfaced via a service to store all data. Use either Java/.Net/Nodejs (again if particular about js framework try npm SOAP) tech stack to create a Web service confirming to QBWC wsdl (https://test.developer.intuit.com/QBWC/TroubleshootWebServiceFS/Service.asmx?wsdl) that will pull all the from this backend and then register this endpoint at QBWC.

Coming to vert.x,
That must work out if you make sure in vert.x you are using like any other Java code.

[How to incorporate SOAP webservices within a vertx server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32640343/vertx-how-to-incorporate-soap-webservice-within-a-vertx-server)

Comment: Hello WABBIT0111, Would be glad to help with QBWC and make sure you have a successful sync with QBDT, feel free to get back if you stumble across any QBWC releated issues.