# How do I get a CompletableFuture<T> from an Async Http Client request?

Tags: asynchronous, java-8, asynchttpclient, completable-future

On [Async Http Client documentation](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client) I see how to get a `Future<Response>` as the result of an asynchronous HTTP Get request simply doing, for example:

```
AsyncHttpClient asyncHttpClient = new DefaultAsyncHttpClient();
Future<Response> f = asyncHttpClient
      .prepareGet("http://api.football-data.org/v1/soccerseasons/398")
      .execute();
Response r = f.get();
```

However, for convenience I would like to get a `CompletableFuture<T>` instead, for which I could apply a continuation that converts the result in something else, for instance deserializing the response content from Json into a Java object (e.g. [SoccerSeason.java](https://gist.github.com/fmcarvalho/307525062873c83c82ad662a2c7a3f74)). This is what I would like to do:

```
AsyncHttpClient asyncHttpClient = new DefaultAsyncHttpClient();
CompletableFuture<Response> f = asyncHttpClient
     .prepareGet("http://api.football-data.org/v1/soccerseasons/398")
     .execute();
f
     .thenApply(r -> gson.fromJson(r.getResponseBody(), SoccerSeason.class))
     .thenAccept(System.out::println);
```

According to [Async Http Client documentation](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client) the only way to do this is through an `AsyncCompletionHandler<T>` object and using a promise. So I built an [auxiliary method](https://gist.github.com/fmcarvalho/fcfe91effc495bae5fe1110b13b5c26d) to that end:

```
CompletableFuture<Response> getDataAsync(String path){
    CompletableFuture<Response> promise = new CompletableFuture<>();
    asyncHttpClient
            .prepareGet(path)
            .execute(new AsyncCompletionHandler<Response>() {
                @Override
                public Response onCompleted(Response response) throws Exception {
                    promise.complete(response);
                    return response;
                }
                @Override
                public void onThrowable(Throwable t) {
                    promise.completeExceptionally(t);
                }
            });
    return promise;
}
```

With this utility method I can rewrite the previous example just doing:

```
getDataAsync("http://api.football-data.org/v1/soccerseasons/398")
    .thenApply(r -> gson.fromJson(r.getResponseBody(), SoccerSeason.class))
    .thenAccept(System.out::println);
```

Is there any better way of getting a `CompletableFuture<T>` from an Async Http Client request?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

With AHC2:

```
CompletableFuture<Response> f = asyncHttpClient
     .prepareGet("http://api.football-data.org/v1/soccerseasons/398")
     .execute()
     .toCompletableFuture();
```

Comment: Could you include a `CompletableFuture<T>` usage example in `Readme.md` of [AHC2 repo](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client)? I think it's useful.

Comment: @StephaneLandelle The documentation says - "Beware that canceling this CompletableFuture won't properly cancel the ongoing request. There's a very good chance we'll return a CompletionStage instead in the next release." Wondering if there's a proper CompletableFuture available in the latest release, which will cancel the requests correctly too?