# Javascript async await equivalent of C# Task.Delay

Tags: javascript, async-await

Similar to this question
[Java Equivalent of C# async/await?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16539245/java-equivalent-of-c-sharp-async-await)
which asked about **Java**, I am asking about **Javascript**.

How do I write the following C# in Javascript in an async /await manner, without using callbacks

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> SomeMethod(string myStr) {
  await Task.Delay(2000);

  //== continue here after 2 secs
}
```

Comment: according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5449956/how-to-add-a-delay-for-a-2-or-3-seconds this does not block the main thread like the `async / await` in javascript. i would say yes, they are pretty the same

Comment: @Ivar yes i like the one liner: await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 2000));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write your own delay method.

```
function delay(time) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve(), time);
    });
}
```

To use it

```
async function someMethod(myStr) {
    await delay(2000);

    // Continue here after 2 secs
}
```

Comment: Ok, as suggested by another link above, there is a one liner await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 2000));