# Async with single thread in Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, kotlin

I read some stack overflow answers about sync, async, and threading on [post A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34681101/13892944) and [post B](https://stackoverflow.com/a/748235/13892944). The main point I got from the post is **"multithreading is only one kind of asynchrony. Threading is about workers; asynchrony is about tasks"** from post A and **"Technically, the concept of synchronous/asynchronous really does not have anything to do with threads"** from post B

I believe this is general idea in programming world. so what I wonder about this is "is it true in android(java/kotlin)? if so, what other methodologies to implement asynchrony tasks ***in single thread*** in java/kotlin?" Can anybody give me an example in android specific ? (or in java/kotlin is welcomed too)

Comment: `I believe this is general idea in programming world. so what I wonder about this is "is it true in android(java/kotlin)?` you say that this is a general idea for all of programming, then ask if it is true for java or kotlin, do these not form part of the programming world ?

Comment: @a_local_nobody if you mean that my thought applies to java or kotlin too, could you give me an example or any link that exmplains it well plz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the concept of `async/await`, found in languages like `C#` and `JavaScript`.

`Java` doesn't support this by default, nor are their any popular/widely used libraries that using it. You can simulate it using `Futures` like here [Java Equivalent of C# async/await?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16539245/java-equivalent-of-c-sharp-async-await)
but its kind sketch.

`Kotlin` has the `suspend` function modifier that simulates this functionality. Here is a break down https://www.raywenderlich.com/books/kotlin-coroutines-by-tutorials/v2.0/chapters/5-async-await

Comment: Basically what you are saying is that "there are not any popular/widely used libraries that using async works with single thread in Java/Kotlin" which means most of async works in Android(Java/Kotlin) should be involving multi threads (suspend also involves background threads)?

Comment: Yes, Kotlin's `suspend` is close to `async/await` functionality because it is uses a "state machine". But unlike `C#` and `Javascript` you can't run it on the main thread without blocking the main thread. AFAIK. IMO `async/await` w/ a single thread is a quick solution to blocking problems, but a moot point for `Android`. In `Android` the main thread is already doing a lot of work as it is, making it do more work won't result in a better experience, it just wouldn't crash due to a not responding error.